# Handling KeyError in conditional statement python when reading json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

So I am reading through two json files to check if the keys file name and file size exist. In one of the files i only have the key filename and not file size. When running my script it keeps through a KeyError , i would like to instead make it print out the file name/names that do not have the key file size.

The error i get is :

```
if data_current['File Size'] not in data_current:
KeyError: 'File Size'


file1.json

{"File Name": "personDetails.json Exists", "File Size": "7484"}
{"File Name": "agent.json Not Exists"}

file2.json

{"File Name": "personDetails.json Exists", "File Size": "7484"}
{"File Name": "agent.json Not Exists",  "File Size": "9484"}
```

My code is as follows :

```
with open('file1.json', 'r') as f, open('file2.json', 'r') as g:

    for cd, pd in zip(f, g):

        data_current = json.loads(cd)
        data_previous = json.loads(pd)
        if data_current['File Size'] not in data_current:
            data_current['File Size'] = 0


        if data_current['File Name'] != data_previous['File Name']:  # If file names do not match
            print " File names do not match"
        elif data_current['File Name'] == data_previous['File Name']:  # If file names match
            print " File names match"
        elif data_current['File Size'] == data_previous['File Size']:  # If file sizes match
            print "File sizes match"
        elif data_current['File Size'] != data_previous['File Size']: # 


            print "File size is missing"
        else:
            print ("Everything is fine")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a key exists in dictionary by doing `if 'File Size' not in data_current:`

```
>>> data = {"File Size": 200} # Dictionary of one value with key "File Size"
>>> "File Size" in data # Check if key "File Size" exists in dictionary
True
>>> "File Name" in data # Check if key "File Name" exists in dictionary
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if key in dict` approach is likely right for you, but it's worth also knowing about the `get()` method of dict objects.

You can use this to attempt to retrieve a key's value from the dictionary and if it's not present it'll return a default value instead - `None` by default or you can specify your own value:

```
data = {"foo": "bar"}
fname= data.get("file_name")  # fname will be None
default_fname = data.get("file_name", "file not found")  # default_fname will be "file not found"
```

This can be convenient in some situations. You can also write this long hand as:

```
defalut_fname = data["file_name"] if "file_name" in data else "file not found"
```

But I don't like having to write the key that many times!

Answer (score 0):

Use `if 'File Size' not in data_current:`

When using `in` against a dict, python looks at keys, not at the values.